# How to adjust Jupyter Notebook "R" error?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, ggpubr

I'm getting the below error when trying to import library & I'm using R in Jupyter Notebook.

```
library(ggpubr)

Warning message:
"package 'ggpubr' was built under R version 3.6.3"

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggpubr' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace 'rlang' 0.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.5 is required
Traceback:

1. library(ggpubr)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

I have tried the below codes to adjust it ,But it didn't workout

```
remove.packages("ggpubr")
```

&

```
install.packages("ggpubr")
```

&

```
update.packages(Yes)
```

Comment: What version of R are you running?

Comment: How can i check the R version in Jupyter Notebook.  whether i can use the below code 'R.version ()' ?

Comment: Run `version` in a notebook cell to get your R version.

Comment: version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)

Comment: You could try `install.packages('rlang')`

Comment: I download the rlang package, what is the library that i should use to instead of the below , (its from 'ggpubr' )
```
Error in ggarrange(a, b, c, d, ncol = 2, nrow = 2): could not find function "ggarrange"
Traceback:
```

Comment: Does library(ggpubr) work now?

Comment: No. still the  library(ggpubr)  doesn't work even though I install ('rlang')